# TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance is not working

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm building my `TextView` dynamically and I've been trying to add a style using `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance` but nothing is changing.

I've also tried to change the `color` or the `size` for the `TextView` to see if anything changes but with no results.

Here is a part of the code:

```
        LinearLayout frameLayout = new LinearLayout(SubmitBills.this);
        frameLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        frameLayout.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);

        ImageView icon = new ImageView(SubmitBills.this);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
        icon.setLayoutParams(params);

        LinearLayout dataLayout = new LinearLayout(SubmitBills.this);
        dataLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout one = new LinearLayout(SubmitBills.this);
        one.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        ITextView billerLabel = new ITextView(SubmitBills.this);
        ITextView biller = new ITextView(SubmitBills.this);
        ITextView dueAmtLabel = new ITextView(SubmitBills.this);
        ITextView dueAmt = new ITextView(SubmitBills.this);

        billerLabel.setText(R.string.biller_label);
        biller.setText(billsDtList.get(i).getBillerDesc());
        dueAmtLabel.setText(R.string.dueAmount);
        dueAmt.setText(billsDtList.get(i).getDueAmount());

        billerLabel.setPadding(0, 0, 30, 0);
        biller.setPadding(0, 0, 30, 0);
        dueAmtLabel.setPadding(0, 0, 30, 0);
        dueAmt.setPadding(0, 0, 30, 0);

        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(billerLabel, R.style.darkTextStyleRegular);
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(biller, R.style.darkTextStyleRegular);
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(dueAmtLabel, R.style.darkTextStyleBold);
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(dueAmt, R.style.darkTextStyleRegular);

        one.addView(billerLabel);
        one.addView(biller);
        one.addView(dueAmtLabel);
        one.addView(dueAmt);

        dataLayout.addView(one);

        frameLayout.addView(icon);
        frameLayout.addView(dataLayout);

        bills.addView(frameLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TextView myTextView= findViewById(R.id.txt1);
myTextView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.yourStyle);
```

(The first parameter of setTextAppearance is the context)